# Совмещение статической верстки с адаптивной

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Верстаю сейчас сайт, в макете контейнер в ширину целых 1560 пикселей, но нужно, чтобы сайт помещался в экраны меньшего разрешения, пропорционально сужаясь, без появления горизонтального скрола. Так же есть мобильная версия при ширине экрана меньше 500, ширина контейнера 400 пикселей. Вот сам [сайт](http://cl86782.tmweb.ru/b/index.html).

В отладчике гугл хром при уменьшении ширины экрана все работает как надо - размер сайта подгоняется под размер окна, так же при пресечении 500 пикселей корректно отображается мобильная версия. Но в действительности, когда я открываю страницу на других, более узких мониторах, контент выходит за пределы экрана.

До этого приходилось верстать просто статические сайты и все работало как надо. В чем может быть причина? Возможно ли вообще такое реализовать?

Comment: media для css .

Answer (score 0):

Используете медиа-запросы.
Советую использовать Grid (Адаптивная сетка). Ссылка: [тык](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout).
Рекомендую изучить следующую [статью](https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy/).
Ниже приведен пример медиа запросов

```css
  // Ландшафтный экран телефоны
  @media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
 
  // От ландшафтного экрана телефона до потретного планшета
  @media (max-width: 767px) { ... }
 
  // От портретного планшета до ландшафтного экрана и настольных дисплеев
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }
 
  // Большой дисплей
  @media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильно надо верстать, не забывая про простейшее сравнение чисел.

Вот ваш стиль:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px)
.content-wrapper {
  min-width: 1100px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Как по-вашему, какова будет ширина контента при ширине окна, скажем, 800px? Отож. Оттуда и горизонтальный скроллинг.

Если в стилях `min-width` какого-нибудь элемента БОЛЬШЕ, чем `min-width`, заданный в media query (а в данном случае это 0 пикселей), то при размере экрана меньшем, чем `min-width` этого элемента, скроллинг появится стопроцентно.